# How to enable warning from TypeScript when trying to access properties of an optional field?

Tags: typescript

Accessing property of `undefined` is a common error in JS. Is there a way that TypeScript can help prevent the following error?

```
class Person {
    name?: {
        firstName: string;
        lastName: string;
    };
    age: number;
}

let bob: Person = {
    age: 20
}

console.log(bob.name.firstName) // no expected warning
```

Comment: Turn on `--strictNullChecks`.

Comment: I've always just used `if (person.name) {...}`, but I'd love to know if there is a more elegant way of doing this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way that TypeScript can help prevent

Use `--strictNullChecks`.

## More

- Search the internet for `strictNullChecks` TypeScript.
- I wrote some docs on this option as well : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html